# Separate "View only" and "Edit only" Excel pages

Tags: excel, excel-2013

so im thinking if theres a way to connect 2 spreadsheets. 1 for viewing lets name it SpreadsheerA and another one for editing SpreadsheetB. The reason for this is im trying to make SpreadsheetA with only 5 columns for example and SpreadsheetB with 7 columns. I'm planning to sort the table based on the last 2 columns but i want it hidden hence the SpreadsheetA having 5visible+2hidden columns and it being an uneditable spreadsheet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, in Sheet 1 put `=Sheet2!A1` in cell A1, `=Sheet2!A2` in cell A2 etc.

Now hide the columns you want to hide and protect Sheet 1.

Sheet 1 will now mirror sheet 2, but will be uneditable.

(If you want to do this across different files, this is also possible using the same technique.)

Comment: hello im having trouble following simple instructions. what if my table is still growing? should i manually mirror each sell each time i add a new row?

Comment: No problem, well, you could manually add new references, or you could just copy and paste the references across a range that is larger than you are likely to need. For example, if your range is currently A1:Z1000, you could just reference A1:AZ10000 and then you can be fairly sure you'll never run out of references.

Comment: i have a header and cant seem to reference it on sheet2. whenever i do =sheet1!A1 it only gives me 0 value on the cell

Comment: Are your sheets in different workbooks? If they are, click the cell you want to be a mirror and type '='. Now go to the other workbook and click the corresponding cell. You'll see something like ='TESTWORKBOOK.XLSX'Sheet1!A1. Now your cell is mirroring the other file

Comment: nope, im editing on the same spreadsheet how can i do this when im using the same file for 2 spreadsheets? sorry kind of a noob in excel

Comment: That's fine. You've got 2 sheets, I'm assuming they are named Sheet 1 and Sheet 2. I'm also assuming your data is in Sheet 2 and you want it to be mirrored in Sheet 1. Go to sheet 1 and click cell A1. Now type '=' and click cell A1 in sheet 2. You should see whatever is in Sheet 2 replicated in sheet 1.

Comment: Then just drag the formula down and across to copy it. If you want to hide zeroes, you could use the formula '=IF(Sheet2!A1="","",Sheet2!A1). I'm off now, but if you're still struggling I'll try and log on tomorrow.

Comment: it's fine man. thanks for helping and answering my questions. i guess ill just work around with all the info you gave me. thanks for giving me some of your time!